# How well can they localize the sources of these marsquakes using only a single seismometer? Does being in the shadow zone of the core help or hinder?

Tags: seismology, data-analysis, mars, instrumentation

Phys.org's April 23, 2022 [Two largest marsquakes to date recorded from planet's far side](https://phys.org/news/2022-04-largest-marsquakes-date-planet-side.html) links to [The Far Side of Mars: Two Distant Marsquakes Detected by InSight](https://pubs.geoscienceworld.org/ssa/tsr/article/2/2/88/613226/The-Far-Side-of-Mars-Two-Distant-Marsquakes) which contains the image below.

Answers to [How are marsquake epicenters determined using only one seismometer?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40505/12102) tell us that the presence of both s and p waves and their different propagation speeds helps.

But in the case of these to well publicized and studied events I'd like to ask more specifically:

**Question:** How well can they localize the sources of these marsquakes using only a single seismometer? Does being in the shadow zone of the core help or hinder?

---

[image]

> Figure 1. Summary of Martian interior models from Stähler et al. (2021)
> and ray paths for seismic phases from events presented in this article.
> (a) The travel time curves are computed using the TauP package (Crotwell
> et al., 1999) for a source depth of 50 km. The phase picks that the
> Marsquake Service (MQS) identified for these events are indicated with
> crosses, with varying symbol sizes to schematically reflect the pick
> uncertainties. The distant events are S1000a and S0976a. For comparison, also shown is S0173a, an event at 30° that locates at Cerberus
> Fossae. For all three events, high-amplitude phase arrivals have been
> identified as direct P/S for S0173a and single free-surface reflections PP/SS
> for S1000a and S0976a. For S1000a, a weak Pdiff phase that is diffracted
> along the core–mantle boundary is also identified. The vertical dashed
> lines and gray shaded bars mark the event distances and uncertainties
> from Table S1, respectively. (b) The structural models are not constrained
> by observations for depths below ∼800 km for P waves (hatched region;
> Khan et al., 2021), hence the Pdiff travel times are purely from model
> predictions. (c) Illustrates the ray paths of the identified phases using a
> Mars model with a core radius of 1855 km.

---

Related and potentially helpful in Earth Science SE:

- [What could be causing microseisms on Mars?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/16510/6031)

and in Space Exploration SE:

- [Just how sensitive is the Insight seismometer?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34022/12102)
- [What is VBB recentering (InSight lander's Very Broad Band seismic pendulums)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34538/12102)
- [How are the most sensitive seismometers on Mars protected from the most powerful jackhammer on Mars just a few feet away?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36032/12102)
- [What are InSight's barometric and seismic digitization rates and frequency responses when it "listens to the wind"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32694/12102)
- [Plot of the thermally-induced tilt in Martian surface during solar eclipse by Phobos? (slope of 1 atom per meter?)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/52337/12102)
- [Has Mars quaked yet? Any scientific speculation when it might?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38543/12102)
- [How was InSight's vertical seismometer (accelerometer) tested in Earth's stronger gravity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32268/12102)